# Parsing PEP 3118 buffer protocol format strings

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, buffer, cython, pep3118

I am interested in passing binary data between python, numpy, and cython using the buffer protocol. Looking at [PEP 3118](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3118/#additions-to-the-struct-string-syntax), there appear to be some additions to the struct string-syntax that add support for useful features such as named fields and nested structs.

However, it appears that support for the full range of buffer syntax is limited in all of those three places. For example, say I have the following cython struct:

```
ctypedef packed struct ImageComp:
    uint32_t width
    uint32_t height
    uint8_t *pixels

#Here is the appropriate struct format string representation
IMAGE_FORMAT = b'T{L:width:L:height:&B:pixels:}'
```

Attempting to extract the PEP-3118 compliant bytes string as follows

```
cdef void *image_temp = malloc(sizeof(ImageComp))
IMAGE_SIZE = sizeof(ImageComp)
IMAGE_FORMAT = (<ImageComp[:1]>image_temp)._format
IMAGE_DTYPE = np.asarray(<ImageComp[:1]>image_temp).dtype
free(image_temp)
```

Fails with this error message:
`Invalid base type for memoryview slice: ImageComp`
since typed memoryviews cannot be created if they contain pointers.

Similarly, creating a `view.array` using my custom string or using the python `struct` module's `calcsize` function will give a warning like `struct.error: bad char in struct format`.

I can manually create and fill a `Py_buffer` object as described [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/buffer.html), but attempting to convert this to a numpy array with `np.asarray` yields `ValueError: 'T{L:width:L:height:&B:pixels:}' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string`.

With all of this in mind, I have the following questions:

1. Is there any module in the standard python library that takes advantage of the complete `PEP 3118` specification?
2. Is this struct format syntax defined formally anywhere (i.e. with a PEG grammar)?
3. Is there a way to force cython or numpy to automatically generate a valid format string if it contains pointers?

Comment: Looking at [this](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/b57e43300b594f1cbe6604d03047fc7fe8ed72c7/Cython/Compiler/PyrexTypes.py), under the `valid_dtype` function, there is a comment about how `Pointers are not valid (yet)` for base types for memoryviews.

Comment: Other relevant files on the cython end: cython's buffer protocol format processing code appears to be [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/3a5a2e3b5ccdd5b932d6ff387d8f830e1dd87ab9/Cython/Utility/Buffer.c), while the code for templating typed memoryview is [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/b8e2e12ec12e5fb369c7af0f54ea511f49b9df2c/Cython/Utility/MemoryView_C.c).

Comment: The problem with pointers: this is a very stupid format. You need some additional (meta) information to handle them properly: 1) is data pointed to by pointer shared, owned or just referenced (i.e. who is responsible for freeing the resources and how is it ensured that the pointers don't become dangling). 2) How big is memory (needed when a deep copy should be performed). Without the above information one cannot safely handle pointers (also not in a numpy-array). ctypes has the needed meta-information and thus can handle pointers - but they have much more overhead than simple structs.

Comment: @ead Yeah, there are some serious limitations to this PEP3118 format (not to mention that there are no sized C99 types or features like unions). In my use case though, I would have cython/c own the data pointed to by the pointer and be responsible for malloc-ing and free-ing the pointer. I could then write python-accessible functions to access the data pointed to by the pointer. The size information is present here (`width * height * 4 * sizeof(uint8_t)` bytes), although this might not be true generally. The pointer could just be exposed as an untyped uintptr_t not meant for direct use.

Comment: @ead I was actually intending to use this in the context of a `SlotMap` data structure that I have implemented in cython (described [here](https://seanmiddleditch.com/data-structures-for-game-developers-the-slot-map/amp/) and [here](https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/game-engine-containers-handle_map-r4495/)). On the python side, users would only get access to a `uint64_t` handle that would point indirectly to the bytes of a struct stored in an array of structs. I can include that cython code here if it would help.

Comment: So why not use `b'T{L:width:L:height:Q:pixels:}'`. The meta-information about pointers is somewhere in your programm-logic (as opposed to be a part of the data), so adding  "interpret pixels as an address" isn't that big deal anymore, even if it is maybe not the most stellar solution.

Comment: @ead That certainly could work in this case. The problem would then be that I would have to create all of these format strings from scratch, rather than use the code in my second snippet to generate them for me. I could just replace the uint8_t * pixels with uintptr_t pixels in the struct definition itself, but then type information is definitely lost, but now on the cython side as well.